# Make react redux connect into a react hook (props TypeError issue)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, types, react-redux

I'm trying to make a react (redux) hook that allows me to use that instead of 'connect' my component to `react-redux`

So far my attempt has been to make a hook like this:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

function useAuthHeaders(props) {
  const [authHeader, setAuthHeader] = useState({
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + props.state.token,
    },
  })
  return [authHeader]
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  state,
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(useAuthHeaders)
```

Then I tried to use it like this:

```
import useAuthHeaders from '../../hooks/useAuthHeaders'

export default function FeedsForm(props) {
  // other states (useState)

  const [authHeader] = useAuthHeaders()

  useEffect(() => {
    // etc.
```

but it completely breaks my app

[image: TypeError message: Cannot set property 'props' of undefined]

I don't see why this shouldn't be possible since it is durable to connect a react functional component to `react-redux`. However I do see the type issue there would be since my hooks parameters aren't really provided as props in the usual react way (jsx prop-attributes). But it is following the guidelines for custom hooks https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html

Comment: You cannot connect a hook, use [useSelector](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks) instead of connect.

Comment: @HMR this would have been my first choice but the project is locked to `"react-redux": "^6.0.1",` so it's currently not an option.

Comment: If that's the case then you can't write a custom hook that has access to redux state.